# Weird behaviour of a seconds elapsed function

Tags: java, date, calendar

Class level variables:

```
    static int secondsInterval = 100000000;
    static long secondsSpecial=0;
    static Date dateSecondsReg;
```

I have the following function I pass two arguments to this function:

1. The number of seconds which have elapsed since a certain date.
2. The actual date (Beginning date) since when the calculation commences.

the method is:

```
public static void secondsToNotify(long seconds, String d){
        Date dt = Convert(d); 
        System.out.println(""+dt);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        cal.setTime(dt); 
        secondsSpecial = secondsInterval*(1+(seconds/secondsInterval)); 
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, (int) secondsSpecial);
        
        dateSecondsReg = cal.getTime(); 
        System.out.println(""+dateSecondsReg);
        System.out.println(""+secondsSpecial);
    }
```

I pass the following arguments to the method:

```
secondsToNotify(2682810000L, "1929-01-02");
```

To my amazement the resulting date, instead of being in future is in past:

### Results

```
1929-01-02
Mon Jun 17 17:08:24 IST 1878
2700000000
```

Cant understand where I am going wrong, any hints?

Comment: Just an advice. Variable names starts with lowercase.

Comment: They are in my case? except for Dt.

Comment: Dt and Cal are variables too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in:

```
Cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, (int) secondsSpecial);
```

You're casting a long to int, and unless I've miscounted a zero or two I think your long is bigger than Integer.MAX_VALUE. So this will wrap around to some negative number, and there's your subtraction.

(For the record, starting variable names with capital letters is very bad style in Java, and made your code quite hard to read.)

Comment: We can also add that casting long to int is a REALLY bad idea as you have a chance to loose information !

Comment: This was exactly what was happening, the result of long to int was becoming negative.

Answer (score 3):

`seconds / secondsInterval` will be carried out in *integer arithmetic* which means that any remainder is lost.

Pre-multiplying by 1.0 will force the calculation to be carried out in floating point:

```
1.0 * seconds / secondsInterval
```

(**P.S.** Eventually, your cast `(int)secondsSpecial` will give you trouble if `secondsSpecial` gets large: you need to rethink that. One idea would be to drop all your `int` types. Then, as a workaround to `Calendar.add` having an `int` as the interval argument, convert `secondsSpecial` to years and seconds and add the intervals successively.)

Comment: So what do you suggest has to be done in order to get the correct values for all use cases, the date I get is still in the past. its changed to year 97 now.

Comment: @AstralProjection I've elaborated with a suggestion. But it's not particularly trivial. I think some folk use Joda Time which, I believe, has better interfaces.

Comment: Yes I will go with what you advised, sounds pretty neat! I cannot use Joda, some restrictions due to the platform I am working on.

Comment: It can get *horrible* though: especially if you have to consider leap-seconds let alone leap years. But I doubt that many Java implementations support leap seconds so you might be safe there. Also, if you want to go far back then note that September 1752 is a short month.

Comment: how about doing addition while in `long`. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

you have an integer overflow here

```
Cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, (int) secondsSpecial);
```

that cast to int results in  `-1594967296` being passed

Check `System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);` will give 2147483647 ie 2^31 -1

since it seems that `Calendar.add` only takes in `int` as increment how about

```
cal.setTimeInMillis(dt.getTime() + secondsSpecial)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles here, this is what I came up with as of now ( Not too robust though, improving it)

```
public class testSplSec {


    static int secondsInterval = 100000000;
    static long secondsSpecial=0;
    static Date dateSecondsReg; 
    static Integer intValue;


    public static void secondsToNotify(long seconds, String d){
        Date dt = Convert(d); 
        System.out.println(""+dt);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        cal.setTime(dt); 
        secondsSpecial = secondsInterval*(1+(seconds/secondsInterval));     
        System.out.println(""+(secondsSpecial));

        long hour = (secondsSpecial /60)/60; 
        System.out.println(""+hour);

        if(hour >= Integer.MAX_VALUE){

        }else{
            intValue =  (int) (long)hour; 
        }
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR,intValue);    
        dateSecondsReg = cal.getTime(); 
        System.out.println(""+dateSecondsReg);
        System.out.println(""+secondsSpecial);
    }

    public static Date Convert(String S){

        String DateStr = S;
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(DateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        java.sql.Date d1 = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());

        return d1; 
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        secondsToNotify(2682810000L, "1929-01-02"); 
    }

}
```